# Does quasi-metric space generate a topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $d$ be a quasi-metric on $X$. That is, $\forall~x,y,z\in X$

> $d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$ and $d(x,y)\le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$

Thus symmetry is absent in the above definition.

Now if we define open balls as usual i.e. $B(x,\delta)=\{y\in X:d(x,y)<\delta\}$ then is it possible to show that $\mathcal B=\{B(x,\delta):x\in X,\delta>0\}$ forms a base for some topology on $X?$

I am terribly stuck at this problem due to the absence of symmetry. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just following the definitions?

To show that $\mathcal B$ is a base for a topology of $X$, we have to show that $\mathcal B$ covers $X$, and that whenever $B_1,B_2\in\mathcal B$ and $y\in B_1\cap B_2$, there exists $B\in\mathcal B$ such that $y\in B\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$, right?

$\mathcal B$ covers $X$ because $x\in B(x,1)\in\mathcal B$.

Suppose $y\in B_1\cap B_2$ where $B_1,B_2\in\mathcal B$; say $B_1=B(x_1,\delta_1)$ and $B_2=B(x_2,\delta_2)$ for some $x_1,x_2\in X$ and $\delta_1,\delta_2\gt0$.

Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_1-d(x_1,y),\ \delta_2-d(x_2,y)\}\gt0$, and let $B=B(y,\delta)$. Then $y\in B(y,\delta)\in\mathcal B$; we have to show that $B\subseteq B_1$ and $B\subseteq B_2$.

To see that $B\subseteq B_1$, suppose $z\in B$. Then
$$d(x_1,z)\le d(x_1,y)+d(y,z)\lt d(x_1,y)+\delta\le\delta_1,$$
so $z\in B_1$.